# "particularly not knowing that thought leadership even existed"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A sales representative in Australia jumped on SAS’ Hub to ask if anyone had experience dealing with a specific competitive situation, Graebe says. Within 24 hours, he had six answers representing four countries and seven departments.
>   “There is no way this sales representative could have gathered this type of feedback via email as quickly and broadly as he did via the Hub,” Graebe says, “**particularly not knowing that thought leadership even existed**.”

What does last sentence mean?

> **particularly not knowing that thought leadership even existed**

Comment: Could you add a link to the source? There appears to be at least one bit of careless wording in that quote already.

Comment: Which part of the last sentence don't you understand? *thought leadership*? It helps if you are more specific.

Comment: this part "knowing that thought "

Comment: If you read it as "knowing that **thought leadership even existed**" does it become clearer? *thought leadeship* is a concept that is probably discussed more broadly in the source of your text.

Comment: @laugh: its not actually referenced. I gather that "thought leadership" means "expertise" and that sentence is trying to say "[faster than email] especially since he didn't know anyone who might even have the answer".  This may actually be what peter is trying to say also :)

Answer (score 1):

In the article [*9 Benefits of An Internal Social Network*](http://m.ragan.com/Main/Articles/9_benefits_of_an_internal_social_network_45790.aspx) the virtues of having a company internal centralised hub where issues and ideas can be discussed is extolled.

In your passage

> particularly not knowing that thought leadership even existed

is in reference to the ability for someone **new** to an effort to be able to reach out and contact levels of expertise outside of their own geography or specialisation.  Also it becomes a store or knowledge base for others to be able to openly see, whereas using emails is only inclusive of people on an address list.

So the passage is saying that knowledge of where thought leadership may be in an organisation is not necessary and that having a central hub will expose it.

The mechanism is similar to stackexchange.com